# How to fetch strapi data based on relation where attributes name value matches input

Tags: url, strapi

The Strapi query endpoint `http://localhost:1337/api/foods?populate=*` generates complete food data including the category data too, i want to retrieve the data which only category as "Indian food".

How to acheive this with the help of only the url query, I know I can filter the data after fetching accordingly but I want to try doing it by the `url` itself

```
[{"id":1,
  "attributes": {
    "title":"Pav Bhaji",
    // other data
    "categories":{
      "data":[
      {
        "id":2,
        "attributes":{
          "name":"Indian Food",
          // other data
          "slug":"indian",
        }
      }
      ]
    }
  }
}
,{"id":3,
  "attributes": {
    "title":"Chines Noodles",
    // other data
    "categories":{
      "data":[
      {
        "id":7,
        "attributes":{
          "name":"Spicy Food",
          // other data
          "slug":"spicy"
        }
      },
      ]
    }
  }
}]
```